# Drupal email authentication forwarding to correct node

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

In Drupal I generate an email using the Rules module. In the email it sends a link to the node updated.

http://mysite/node/20

The nose can only be seen by authenticated users.

When I click on that link and I am logged in it goes to the node. If I am not logged in and click on the link you would get an accessed denied.

I use [Redirect 403 to User Login](http://drupal.org/project/r4032login) module to direct people to the login form. After logging in the user is taken to the  page. Would it be possible to take the user to http://mysite/node/20 which was sent in the email?

How would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after logging in, user will be redirected to which page?

the drupal's query string "destination" can redirect you after submitting a form for example..

action="/action/do-form?destination=node/20"

and after submission, you get redirected to that page. so if 403 redirect module collects the user previous page - which is in that case node 20, it should work without a problem :-/

Comment: I was using the Login destination module and had not ticked " Return user to where he/she came from. (Preserve destination)"